# Retrofit go to onFailure while incorrect data input

Tags: java, android, gson

I'm using Retrofit in Android to login with POST method to server with API and response it back. When I insert the data that already have in the server to login it will go to `onResponse` but when I insert the data that have no in the server in will to go `onFailure` but in my API I handled when have no data it will response status `False`. This is the message when it go to `onFailure`:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 56 path $.data

**SignInService.java**

```
public interface SignInService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/signIn/")
    Call<SignInRespone> signIn(@Field("email") String email,
                               @Field("password") String password);

}
```

**SignInResponse.java**

```
public class SignInRespone {
    @SerializedName("success")
    private boolean success;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private Data data;

    public boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class Data {
        @SerializedName("id")
        private int id;
        @SerializedName("username")
        private String username;
        @SerializedName("email")
        private String email;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }
}
```

**SignInRequest.java**

```
public class SignInRequest {
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public SignInRequest(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**SignInActivity.java**

```
public void signIn(){
        signInService = ServiceGenerator.createService(SignInService.class);
        Call<SignInRespone> call= signInService.signIn("jonh1@gmail.com","12345");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SignInRespone>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SignInRespone> call, Response<SignInRespone> response) {
                Log.e(">>>>",response.body().getData().getEmail());
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SignInRespone> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(">>>>", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Send your logcat output for detail.

Comment: Your posted code can be narrowed down to Gson-related stuff only: the exception is clearly telling you that it's expecting `{` but got `[`. You could just post the actual JSON response because it's definitely a JSON-2-mappings issue, not Retrofit.

Comment: {
    "success": true,
    "message": "SignIn successfully!",
    "data": {
        "id": 33,
        "email": "jonh1"
    }
}

Comment: change your server response to `{ "success": false, "message": { "password": "Incorrect username or password." }, "data": {} }` for login fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment when you have logged in success fully server returns correct object that's why no exception, but when email is not present on server it returns data[] instead of data object that's why you are getting exception because you are expecting an object but server returned an array.

Solution:
return data:null form server if email not exists

Comment: when I login with email that have in server it will work and response status true but when I login with email that have no in server it will go to onFailure.

Comment: om.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 56 path $.data

Comment: oky now i got it, it needs to be fixed on server side. when email is not present on server server should return data null instead of data[]

Comment: it should response status false when I login with email that have no exist in server. But I don't know why onFailures method work.

Comment: my server will response status false and message "Incorrect email or password" when I test it on Postman

Comment: show me server response when you are getting exception

Comment: when no have data in server it will response like
{
    "success": false,
    "message": {
        "password": "Incorrect username or password."
    },
    "data": []
}'

Comment: problem is data": []  this is an array not object it should be "data": null or "data":{} or remove data from the response from server